# Qfield crashes when vector elements are touched

Tags: vector, android, qfield, qgis-android

I have a problem with Qfield. I'm using qfield 0.8.8 on OS android 5.1.1
After having installed this Qfield version it does not run.

When I touch a polygon or a line or a point it crashes; in particular I touch a polygon or a line or a point, the lateral window with information appears just for one second and then it crashes.

I don't understand why and how to solve the problem.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I have the same problem but only when I am not in digitize mode.